# How to pass data from ajax to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I dont know how to pass data from ajax to html. I need to pass recived data in ajax to html code from controller i send string i wanna to split it and put in new dropdown menu.. here is code

```
@(postOffices: List[PostOffice])
```

@adminmain("Make a route") {

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      // for any form on this page do the follofing

       $('#selectOffice').blur(function(){
          var valueOfSelect = $('#selectOffice').val();
          $.ajax({
             url: "@routes.PostOfficeController.createRoute()",
             method: "POST",
             data: "valueOfSelect="+valueOfSelect
          }).success(function(response){
              $("#trackForm").show();
          }).error(function(response){
             alert(response + valueOfSelect);
          })
       })
  );

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <select name="postOffices" id="selectOffice">

        @for(postOffice <- postOffices) {

            <option value="@postOffice.name">@postOffice.name</option>

        }


        </select>

    </div>


</div>


<form id="trackForm" name="trackForm" method="POST" style="display : none ;">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <select name="postOffices" id="selectOffice">

            @for(postOffice <- postOffices) {

                <option value=""></option>
```

Comment: If it an array then you need to iterate it and make a `DOM` in loop and then append that DOM in your existing DOM..

Comment: What you receive in `response` inside success method ?

Comment: I recive String like "office1, office2, office3". Can I split this string like  var a  = response   var splitted = a.split(" ") and how to send that in html to be shown in dropdown menu

Answer (score 1):

The return of ajax is an JSON? In this case, you can make this way:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "@routes.PostOfficeController.createRoute()",
         method: "POST",
         data: "valueOfSelect="+valueOfSelect
      }).success(function(response){
          $("#trackForm").show();
         var select = document.getElementById('selectOffice'); //get the select element
         var respJson = JSON.parse(response); //get the response (in text) and transform to JSON object
         respJson.forEach(function(item, itemIndex){ //for in the JSON object
            var opt = document.createElement('option') //create a new option element
            opt.value = item.value; //set the value of otion (NOTE: item.value, where "value" is the parameter os the yout value in the JSON
            opt.innerHTML = item.text;
            select.appendChild(opt); //appende the option in to the select
          })            

      }).error(function(response){
         alert(response + valueOfSelect);
      })
```